# How do I update my hadoop instance after I have changed the source code?

Tags: hadoop

I am using hadoop v1.2.1 and have made a source code change for the project I am working on. The change was to the TaskReport and TaskInProgress classes so additional information would come back in the TaskReport object. I compiled the changes and re-packaged the hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar file and replaced the existing hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar file in the folder where I had unpackaged my hadoop installation.

The map reduce program that I submit to hadoop sees the new properties I added, but the JobTracker doesn't seem to be populating the properties with any data when it creates the TaskReport objects. Do I need to do anything special to get the JobTracker to see these changes, or am I updating hadoop in an incorrect way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out - I needed to restart the hadoop services. From a terminal within the hadoop install folder:

bin/stop-all.sh
bin/start-all.sh